# Is there a way to use same field as rows and columns in google sheets to count unique occurrence between columns?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, crosstab

Looking to convert

| Task id | John | Jan | Juliet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

To

|  | John | Jan | Juliet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John |  | 3 | 1 |
| Jan | 3 |  | 3 |
| Juliet | 1 | 3 |  |

Comment: Could you explain how relevant the 2nd table to the 1st table?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do here, @user2884821. However, I have a feeling that your sample data doesn't represent your real-world data closely enough. For instance, will you really only ever have exactly three people (no more, no fewer) to compare; or will there be more? Will you really be marking tasks with a 1 in your real application; or will you be entering something else (e.g., text) in those cells? In order for anyone here to efficiently and accurately help you, your data needs to be as close to your real-world application data as possible.

Comment: In addition, will your real application always and only have 10 tasks? Or will this number vary?

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler there will be more than 10 tasks and more than 3 people in the real world. I just wanted to simplify the scenario here.

Comment: @NikkoJ. The second table encapsulates unique no of tasks performed by two people (see adjacency).

Comment: @user2884821, I can solve this. However, I will ask that you setup a sample spreadsheet containing the information in your post and share your link here, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." I know some people here frown on asking people to do this, but it is the most efficient way for me to share my solution.

Comment: @ErikTyler please find the link here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13CVP1JV8ZfVNuUlbq1B_7JdNkFIt1pecwws4RpCyqw0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have set up a new sheet ("Erik Help") in your sample spreadsheet.

In B1:

`=SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:1,Sheet1!B1:1<>""))`

This simply fills the top row with your names list, sorted alphabetically.

In A2:

`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:1,Sheet1!B1:1<>"")))`

This fills A2 down with the same names list as above, just vertically.

In B2 is the main formula for the grid (which is then dragged over and down):

`=ArrayFormula(IF( ($A2="") + (B$1="") + ($A2=B$1),, SUM(MMULT(IF((FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$L,Sheet1!$A$2:$A<>"")=1) * (Sheet1!$B$1:$L$1=$A2),1,0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Sheet1!$B$1:$L$1),1,1,0)) * MMULT(IF((FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$L,Sheet1!$A$2:$A<>"")=1) * (Sheet1!$B$1:$L$1=B$1),1,0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Sheet1!$B$1:$L$1),1,1,0)))))`

The first ( ) + ( ) + ( ) tests three OR conditions. If any is true, the cell will be left blank. This is what allows the formula to be dragged all the way right and down without throwing errors and, in essence, "waiting" for new data from the first two formulas above that it can process.

The rest of the formula is too complex to warrant full explanation (e.g., *how* MMULT works in detail), this being a volunteer-run site. (Writing the formula took more time than I generally spend in a day on this or other forums.) But here's the gist.

Two grids — each formed by an MMULT (matrix multiplication) — are SUMmed. The first MMULT will produce a grid the same size as the Sheet1 grid, filled with 1 *only if* two conditions are met: that there was already a 1 in that slot and that the name above matches the name to the right in the "Erik Help" grid. Otherwise, the result for that slot is a zero. The second MMULT forms the same size grid based on the same conditions, only this time it gets a 1 *only if* there is already a 1 and the name above matches the name above the cell in "Erik Help." These two grids are multiplied, and if the product is a 1, we know that BOTH names had a 1 there. Once SUMmed, we get the count of shared projects for those two names.

As this formula is dragged, cell references *not* locked with a dollar sign will adjust, so that two different names will be compared by the two MMULT grids.

Because this solution requires comparing arrays with arrays with arrays, I don't currently see how a further array solution is possible, hence the need for the formulas to be dragged. That is, each of these formulas is already jam-packed with array processing.

Again, the formula is currently dragged all the way to Column Z and down to Row 200. However, it only references up to Column L (which is as far as your current names list goes). If your real world application has more names and thus carries over past Column L, the easiest way to change all of the formulas at once is this:

1. Go to the "Erik Help" sheet (which you can, of course, rename as you like).
2. Hit Ctrl-H to open the Find/Replace dialog box.
3. Enter `$L` in the FIND field and `$?` in the REPLACE field (where `?` will be the new column to which you want the results to extend, e.g., `$M` or `$P`, etc.)
4. Choose "This sheet" from the "Search" drop-down.
5. Check the box next to "Also search within formulas."
6. Click the "Replace all" button.

If the data set shrinks or grows again, do the same steps, just changing the old furthest column reference for the new furthest column reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a super-simple way of doing it which just changes the pair of columns selected in the countifs as the formula moves across and down by relative addressing:

```
=countifs(index($B$2:$D,0,row(A1)),1,index($B$2:$D,0,column(A1)),1)
```

pulled down and across.

[image]

**Attempt at more general solution.**

The question is tagged pivot-table. Although a pivot table approach seems useful, the data is in exactly the wrong format to achieve it. The task would be to transform the data from ones and zeroes to column numbers so

```
1 1 0 => 1 2

1 0 1 => 1 3

1 1 1 => 1 2, 1 3 and 2 3.
```

This can be achieved by generating pairs of numbers as follows and performing a lookup in the original data:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

The formulas to generate these sequences are

```
=ArrayFormula(quotient(mod(sequence(90,1,0),9),3)+1)
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(mod(sequence(90,1,0),3)+1)
```

(9 because there are 3X3 pairs per row of data, 90 because there are 10 rows of data).

The following generates a lookup for each row of data

```
=ArrayFormula(quotient(sequence(90,1,0),9)+1)
```

Putting all this together and wrapping it in a pivot query gives

```
=ArrayFormula(query({vlookup(quotient(sequence(90,1,0),9)+2,{row(B2:D),B2:D},quotient(mod(sequence(90,1,0),9),3)+2,0)*(quotient(mod(sequence(90,1,0),9),3)+1),
vlookup(quotient(sequence(90,1,0),9)+2,{row(B2:D),B2:D},mod(sequence(90,1,0),3)+2,0)*(mod(sequence(90,1,0),3)+1)},
"select count(Col1) where Col1<>0 and Col2<>0 group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

The formula can be generalised to different numbers of rows and columns.